# Convert DateTimeIndex column headings to Date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetimeindex

I've got a dataframe which uses DateTimeIndex for column headings. These are currently displaying in the format 2021-05-01 00:00:00. How can I get rid of the "00:00:00"?

I've looked up a few similar questions here on SO and the general response is using .dt.date:

```
df.columns = df.columns.dt.date
```

but it gives the error AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'.

Do I have something wrong or does .dt just not work for format of dates that I've got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.date
```

because [`.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) is used for working with columns (`Series`):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].dt.date
```

---

```
ser = ser.dt.date
```